# Crash with MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've imported last version of MWPhotoBrowser classes in my project, but when the browser load images form web the app crashes. In implementation i use the same code founded in demo project, if i show local images it's all ok. This is my implementation:

```
[galleryPhotosArray addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue_Screen_iPhone.png"]]];
[galleryPhotosArray addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_iPhone.png"]]];
[galleryPhotosArray addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cellulare.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/apple1.png"]]];

MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
browser.displayActionButton = YES;
browser.displayNavArrows = NO;
browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES;
[browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:0];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];

[browser release];
```

so i add two local images and a random image from google images. The app crashes in two points, sometimes in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.m in this line:

```
self.connection = [NSURLConnection.alloc initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
```

the second point is in SDImageCache.m file, in - (NSString *)cachePathForKey:(NSString *)key inPath:(NSString *)path method
Somebody has this issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error, i've only added ARC support to SDWebImage files.